# How do I compute the point on an histogram where the derivative is zero?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I computed a smoothing on an histogram using the function provided [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/examples/smoothing-a-histogram.html). From what I understand, the point marked at point 0.5 in the image below is where the derivative of the histogram is equal to zero i.e the point where the smoothing curve intersect the bin on descending. How can I automatically or numerically compute this point (by calculation) without visualizing the histogram?
[image]

Comment: The "histogram's derivative" is zero near `0.4`. What happens near `0.5` is that the histogram *itself* becomes zero. Huge difference.

Comment: Thanks @AndrasDeak. Is there a way I can compute the point 0.5 from my data without visualizing the histogram?

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate all the plotting commands from the example.
What it boils down to is the following:

```
y = [randn(1,5001), randn(1,2001)+6];

[heights,centers] = hist(y);
n = length(centers);
w = centers(2)-centers(1);
t = linspace(centers(1)-w/2,centers(end)+w/2,n+1);

dt = diff(t);
Fvals = cumsum([0,heights.*dt]);
F = spline(t, [0, Fvals, 0]);

DF = fnder(F);  % computes its first derivative
```

Now, how do you get actual datapoints for DF? If you read the [manual page for `fnplt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fnplt.html), you'll see that assigning it to a variable will produce data points and no plot.

```
pts = fnplt(DF);
```

Now we just check where data is `> 0` and where the sign changes:

```
pts(2, find(diff(pts(1,:) > 0) == -1) + 1)
```

Let's take it apart:

```
pts(1,:) > 0
```

Creates a logical vector with 1 where the spline is larger than 0 and 0 otherwise.

```
diff(pts(1,:) > 0)
```

Calculates the differences between consecutive elements. When `pts(1,:)` changes from 1 to 0 this will be -1. With `find`, we find the locations of these transitions. This will give us the last points the spline is still positive before going to or through 0.  Finally, we add 1 to get the locations  of the spline after the change of sign.

Comment: Not sure am clear with the last line from your explanation and even when I compute your solution with the same data I have it does not give the same answer as the visualization result as I marked in the histogram image from my question.